# JSON file extract is from the url

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

with this function, iam able to get the data from PHP page into JS. now my route has an id as parameter. iam trying to get data id. this is my js file.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var values = $.getJSON("/json/1");
    values.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    });
});
```

And the route is

```
Route::get('json/{notification_id}','ChartController@speedHistory')->name('speedhistory')
```

in the var `values = $.getJSON("/json/1");` number 1 is hard coded. how i can make it dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id = $("#some_id").val();
    var values = $.getJSON("/json/"+id);

        values.done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        });
```

By this way you can get id by any method in jquery

Comment: does ("#some_id") has to be the same to the one in the rourte. notification_id. for some reason it is not working?

Comment: It will be id of the tag from where you are reading the id to send it as notification id